# Eject USB drives / eject command

Tags: usb-drive, removable-storage, eject

I know that the **`eject`** command can be used to eject almost any hardware component attached, but can it be used to eject USB drives?

Is it possible to eject USB drives and external HDD's with the **`eject`** command?

Comment: Related: the opposite of `eject /dev/sdX` is `sg_start -s /dev/sdX` (from `sg3_utils` package), both use SCSI commands to send to the device.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Nor do they need to be; `eject` is used for opening optical drives, where one cannot pull the media from directly.

Unmounting is sufficient for USB/eSATA/etc. storage devices.

Comment: Hmm, I saw eject hdd as in /dev/sda somewhere. I guess the reference was wrong then.

Comment: You can do it, but it usually doesn't do very much if anything at all.

Comment: This assumes that the device is mounted in the first place, and that carries along another big set of assumptions (it's got a filesystem that you can read, for one).  Imagine that you're erasing a bunch of external drives - they probably never get mounted.  eject is the right thing to use.

Comment: If I'm ever unsure, I `sync` before yanking it out

Comment: Big, fat WARNING: This is NOT completely true. If you do not `eject` it underlying USB Device Driver may still (try to) write AFTER `umount` has returned. This can be clearly seen if drive has a status LED. Yanking the USB stick right after `umount` terminates is RECIPE FOR DISASTER.

Answer (score 123):

Yes. For example:

```
sudo eject /dev/sda
```

Other answers here that indicate that you require mechanical ejection hardware are incorrect.

**Unmounting is not the same thing as ejecting.**

1. If you unmount a volume, you can immediately mount it back, because the underlying device is still available. *In some situations, this could present a security risk.* By ejecting the device, only a reset of the USB subsystem (e.g. a reboot) will reload the device.
2. By ejecting the device, you effectively disable any further access to the device. Only a reset of the USB subsystem (e.g. a reboot) will reload the device. Otherwise, you must physically disconnect the USB device and reconnect it in order to access it again.
3. Before ejecting, this command will unmount all volumes on the device that were mounted.
4. If volumes are in use, this command will fail as with unmount, except that some volumes might be unmounted and some volumes might remain mounted.

Comment: I also had to use `sudo` to get this command to finish (all it would do was unmount the drive before saying it was unable to open the file). Other than that, helpful answer.

Comment: Under-appreciated answer in this thread. Just look at a FAT32 mounted thumb drive, and notice how unmounting and ejecting have a world of difference just in the file explorer (ie: nautilus) alone. A simple Sansa clip would also help demonstrate this.

Comment: The device is still present when executing lsusb. So you don't have to reset the whole USB-Subsystem. Just the device is sufficient. You can use usbreset to do this https://github.com/jkulesza/usbreset
https://github.com/CWempe/usbreset
The usbreset.c files are identically in both projects,

Comment: How do I know that "sda" is the right one? Can I map sda, sdb, etc to the real device names?

Comment: you can use blkid as in `sudo blkid /dev/sda1` to get the label of your usb drive, if it has one. Otherwise you can always revert to the dumb way, which is to check the size of drives listed with `sudo lsblk`. Of course this assumes you know the drive's size, and it differs significantly from other devices...

Answer (score 79):

On **Linux**, `eject` will work, but will not really "finish the job" regarding USB *rotating* drives.

So first, you `eject /dev/sdb` (or `umount` everything).

And **then**, *after proper unmounting*, the best way to unplug a USB external hard-drive is:

```
    udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb
```

or

```
    udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

*This usually causes the drive to spin down gracefully.*

Note: `udisksctl` might be a more "mainstream" tool, compared to `udisks` (the former is already installed on my Debian, the latter isn't & has been [criticised](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/72543) for unnecessary spin up/down).

## Some details

### udisksctl

The [documentation states](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/udisksctl.1.html#id-1.2.2.6) (about the power-off option):

> Arranges for the drive to be safely removed and powered off. On the OS
> side this includes ensuring that no process is using the drive, then
> requesting that in-flight buffers and caches are committed to stable
> storage. The exact steps for powering off the drive depends on the
> drive itself and the interconnect used. For drives connected through
> USB, the effect is that the USB device will be deconfigured followed
> by disabling the upstream hub port it is connected to.
>
> Note that as some physical devices contain multiple drives (for
> example 4-in-1 flash card reader USB devices) powering off one drive
> may affect other drives. As such there are not a lot of guarantees
> associated with performing this action. Usually the effect is that the
> drive disappears as if it was unplugged.

### udisks (deprecated?)

Precisely, the [current implementation](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/udisks/tree/src/helpers/job-drive-detach.c?id=1.0.5#n182) (as of 2014):

- sends SCSI sync-cache command,
- sends SCSI stop command,
- unbinds the usb-storage kernel driver,
- suspends the USB device (power),
- logically disables/removes it from its USB port.

This process is close to the manual procedure that is suggested [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=52627#p311645). Initial answer was [on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56270/how-can-i-spin-down-external-hard-drive/190668#190668).

Comment: `udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb` will deconfigure the usb device even if multiple disks are accessible by it (i.e. usb external raid enclosure). I am not sure that the other drives are safely stopped.

Comment: @Timesquare Yes, that may be a limitation of the tool, as `udiskctl`'s documention (which I quote) points out (using the 4-in-1 USB flash card reader as an example).

Comment: @Totor, thank you, I was not very attentive, had lots of info to read, however, I think many like myself want simple complete solution. I've already wrote my answer for both commands run via shell (bash) function https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679472/446998.

Comment: I find that this works better than using `eject`. [I have several USB drives who’s block devices don’t disappear when I run `eject`](https://superuser.com/q/1761089/954602) but do disappear when I run `udisksctl power-off`.

Answer (score 31):

Manual steps for unmounting disk /dev/sdb (Requires sudo):

```
echo 'offline' > /sys/block/sdb/device/state
echo '1' > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

This will completely power-off the device and detach it from the system. It won't be detected again till it is disconnected and re-attached.

Comment: FWIW this is the only thing that works for me in a Xen dom0 with an external USB cradle - the eject and udisks commands gave errors.

Comment: I was searching for this, i'm in dracut emergency mode and I don't have access to any of the other functions. Thanks!

Comment: `hdparm -Y` is also handy for SATA/IDE drives.

Comment: This worked for me on Debian 11; other things suggested here did not work

Answer (score 7):

If you carefully read **eject(1)** man page you can see that there are 4 methods of ejecting:

```
   -r   This  option specifies that the drive should be ejected using a CDROM
        eject command.

   -s   This option specifies that the drive should  be  ejected  using  SCSI
        commands.

   -f   This option specifies that the drive should be ejected using a remov‐
        able floppy disk eject command.

   -q   This option specifies that the drive should be ejected using  a  tape
        drive offline command.
```

When you call **eject** on HDD/SCSI it issue `ioctl(fd, SG_IO, (void *)&io_hdr);` command (copy from `eject.c` sources).

This is equivalent as you safely remove device in MS Windows or MaxOSX.

For some devices this have special mean. For example Kindle 3 after **eject** command has being moved to charging mode and allow browsing on device, while before screen was locked.

Another utilities do same thing, like this

```
scsi-spin --force --down /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 5):

In osx command line you should use [diskutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/diskutil.8.html) where **LABEL** is label of your usb drive.

```
diskutil eject /Volumes/<LABEL>
```

Answer (score 4):

"Ejecting" has no meaning for hardware without a tray or other loading mechanism (I assume it works with tape drives too).

However, testing with an external USB flash drive tells that `eject` works much like `umount` - with the side effect of making the device nodes disappear, e.g.

```
% ls  /dev/sdc*
/dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
% sudo eject /dev/sdc
% ls  /dev/sdc*
/dev/sdc
```

Note that `/dev/sdc1` has disappeared.

Comment: Never tried it with tapes (`mt rewoffl` is more convenient because it also rewinds), but it *does* work with motorised floppy drives like those found on old Macs and Sun workstations.

Comment: @Alexios interesting.

Answer (score 2):

`udisks --detach /dev/sdX` where (X) is the last letter of your usb device.
It works fine on any linux system.

Comment: Your answer is okay, although maybe it  is a little bit short. I would suggest to elaborate more: what this command does, how, why is this what you suggest, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on two top answers. Just using `udisksctl` results in error if still mounted and `eject` alone does not power-off, only unmounts USB. Therefore I wrote simple one-liner to create a function in `bash`:

```
 e_ject() { 2>/dev/null eject $1;udisksctl power-off -b $1; }; export -f e_ject
```

To use:

```
e_ject /dev/sdX
```

Even more complex and user friendly:

```
'e_ject() { dev=$(mount| grep $1 | awk --field-separator " " '{ FS = " " ; print $1 ; exit }');2>/dev/null eject $dev;udisksctl power-off -b $dev; }; export -f e_ject'
```

To use:

```
e_ject name
```

`name` is searched (`grepped`) in `mount` output of all mounts, expected to be present on one line only, but seems to work fine even if on multiple mounts e.g. for `e_ject sdb` with multiple partitions USB stick. On my system both `eject` and `udisksctl` work with partition (`/dev/sdbx`) parameter.

P.S.

`2>/dev/null` is added due to `eject` outputing an error each time, but result seemed correct.

Not sure a function need to be exported each time of login, but count not find an asnwer to that in `man bash` and do not want to google now. Therefore to be on the safe side below (adding to user profile) is expected to be Ok (multiple re-export did not output any errors):

```
echo 'e_ject() { 2>/dev/null eject $1;udisksctl power-off -b $1; }; export -f e_ject' >> /home/$(id -u -n)/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i will try to explain this better:

udisks command completely remove and power off any usb device mounted or attached in the system
unmount command just unmount the partition ie: dev/sdb1 or whatever but the usb is still present in the system.

So is not the same unmount, eject and detach

udisks = power off the usb

umount = just unmount the partition not the whole pendrive

eject = the same or very close to umount command

Answer (score 0):

In gnome,

```
$ gio mount -e /media/dzmanto/MYUSB
```

ejects a drive MYUSB. No root privileges are required.