# How do I access a flash drive that has been ejected without physically plugging it out and back in?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, usb-drive

When I plug in my flash drive, it gets auto-mounted.  If I right click on the drive and select 'eject', then it's unmounted.

Now, I want to remount the drive in Terminal.  How do I do this?

I've been Googling this for 30 minutes and I haven't found anything that works.

I've read to run '`sudo fdisk -l`' but the USB drive isn't there.  `lsusb` gives me nothing either.

**I want to make this clear**: I know that if I plug the flash drive in again, that I can run mount to find where it is.  However, what I really want to know is, if the drive is still plugged in and was just 'ejected', how do I then remount it from Terminal without physically touching the flash drive?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/eject-usb-drives-eject-command/83587#83587

Comment: Check the output of `mount`. (Without parameters.)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thank you, I think this might be exactly what I need.  I'll report back in any case. :)

Answer (score -3):

Plug the drive back in, go to terminal and execute `mount`. That will show you all mounted devices and where they're mounted. You should see something like:

```
/dev/sdb1 mounted on MOUNTPOINT
```

Eject from GUI, then execute `mount` again from terminal and compare with the output from the 1st `mount` run to confirm which device it was.

To mount for example `/dev/sdb1` to mountpoint `/mnt`, from terminal execute:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Another example mounts an NTFS formatted `/dev/sdb1` as read-only at `/mnt`:

```
mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to know is, how do I find the flash drive if the flash drive is still plugged in and was just unmounted?  I know how to mount it once it's plugged in.  I'll edit my question to make this clearer.