# Command line equivalent to "Safely remove drive"?

Tags: command-line, usb, external-hdd, unmounting

The file managers present in Linux Mint Cinnamon and MATE not only allow you to unmount external drives, but give you the option to "Safely remove" the drives as well, something not present in every Linux distribution.

When I unmount my external hard drive (powered via USB), its indicator light remains lit and I can still hear it spinning. When I "Safely remove" the drive, the light turns off and the disc stops spinning.

**How can I accomplish this same thing via the terminal?** As a side question, is this functionality as simple as `unmount drive > kill power` or is there something more complicated or sophisticated going on behind the scenes? Is this safer than only unmounting the drive and pulling the USB plug out?

Comment: In egneral the only dafe operation is `umount` so I would agree to your assumption that this is nothing more than "unmount drive + kill power""

Comment: Don't modern `window managers` use `udisks` or something similar that work without `root`?

Comment: "Safely Remove" may or may not use `eject` under the hood, which itself calls `umount`. You might see if that replicates the spin-down behavior

Comment: after umount, udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb

Answer (score 6):

[`umount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount) is enough. After that it is completely safe to unplug your device.

I quote from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35509/126755):

> Unmounting is sufficient for USB/eSATA/etc. storage devices.

If you have a lot of cached data to be written on the drive, you may use this command:

**[`sync`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync)**

and then watch the progress with:

```
watch grep -e Dirty: -e Writeback: /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 3):

To safely remove your drive you should :

- unmount the partitions
- powering down your device

`unmount` and `sync` is **sufficient** but it can't provide a **safely remove** for your device.

> To safely unmount and totally remove the drive, enter the following command, replacing /dev/sdb with your own drive’s designation if need be:

```
udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1 && udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

the `udisks manpage`:

```
--detach device_file [--detach-options options]

Detaches (e.g. powering down the physical port the device is connected
to) the device represented by device_file using a comma-separated list of 
options.
```

[Ubuntu USB Storage: How to Safely Remove Drive When Eject and Unmount Are Only Options](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/ubuntu-usb-storage-how-to-safely-remove-drive-when-eject-and-unmount-are-only-options/)

Comment: `udisks` isn't even present on my centos 7 minimal server

Comment: Fedora has` udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX`

Answer (score 2):

After unmounting and `sync`ing, the way to safely remove drive `sdX` without any tools would be (as root):

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX/device/delete
```

If you want to do it through `sudo`, you'll need to do it this way:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block/sdX/device/delete >/dev/null
```

This will tell the kernel that you're going to remove the device. When you do that, the kernel will take care of cleaning up any unfinished tasks with the device and then put the device in question into a ready-for-disconnect state; for example, USB HDDs may spin down when this command is used.

Some versions of the `eject` command are for CD/DVD/BluRay only, but others may have the ability to perform the same procedure as the commands above for any disk device. So depending on distribution, `eject /dev/sdX` might also work, or it might not.

Comment: I wish I could give more than 1 upvote for finally finding a solution that doesn't require utilities I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script: x-drv [device name]; 
I find 'eject' is more for CD/DVD's; 
you might have to modify where your stuff mounts;
I put this in my user 'bin' directory, no './' to run the script

```
# x-drv
# safely remove drive
if [ "$#" = 0 ]
then
   echo -e "\nusage: x-drv drive_name\n"
else
   dev_pth=/media/`whoami`/$1
   if [ -d $dev_pth ]
   then
      tgt_dev=`findmnt -n -r -o SOURCE $dev_pth`
      echo -e "ejecting: $dev_pth - $tgt_dev"
      umount $tgt_dev
      udisksctl power-off -b $tgt_dev
      echo -e ">>> safe to remove <<<\n"
   else
      echo -e "$dev_pth - not mounted\n"
   fi
fi
```

Comment: The most  relevant part, `udisksctl power-off -b block_device`, is a bit buried. It may be worth making it explicit that `uidsksctl power-off` "_Arranges for the drive to be safely removed and powered off_" in udisks2.

Answer (score 1):

One can use utility `udisks2` (instead of `udisks`), in the manner mentioned by GAD3R.

The binary in this package is `udisksctl`.

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/647473/why-udisks-is-not-in-the-system

Comment: It may be worth adding that the command(s) in udisks2 (as opposed to the mentioned usisks counterpart) would be `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1 && udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb`.