# Unwanted permanent umount

Tags: mount, automounting, unmounting, eject

## The problem

I've got a simple question: what's the difference between ejecting [flash drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) using [GNOME Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) (formerly known as [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files)) button (see image below) and [`umount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount) command?

[image: Screenshot of the Nautilus manager after inserting flash drive with marked eject button]

Before you will read rest of this question I encourage you to think if you expect any difference between results of clicking eject button in [GNOME Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) and typing [`umount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount) command? If yes, then what's the difference? If no, then read on...

---

## 1st try: [GNOME Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) eject

When I insert my [flash drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) to my computer's USB socket, [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) automatically mounts it, which is reflected both in [GNOME Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files):

[image: Screenshot of the Nautilus manager after inserting flash drive]

and command line using e.g. [`df`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) command:

```
me@host:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
(...)
/dev/sdf1       3,6G  3,6G     0 100% /media/me/Debian 9.1.0 amd64 1
```

or [`blkid`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) command:

```
root@host:~# blkid
(...)
/dev/sdf1: UUID="XXXX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX" LABEL="Debian 9.1.0 amd64 1" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="XXXXXXXX" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="XXXXXXXX-XX"
/dev/sdf2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="XXXX-XXXX" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="XXXXXXXX-XX"
```

When I click eject button marked with a red circle:

[image: Screenshot of the Nautilus manager after inserting flash drive with marked eject button]

and I run those commands once again, there is no `sdf` string in commands' output (which is probably what I should expect after ejecting `/dev/sdf1`):

```
root@host:~# df -h | grep sdf
root@host:~# df -ah | grep sdf
root@host:~#
```

Note that I added `-a` (`--all`) flag to `df` command and I got the same (empty) result.

```
root@host:~# blkid | grep sdf
root@host:~#
```

Note that now I'm unable to remount `/dev/sdf1` without reinserting my flash drive:

```
root@host:~# mkdir -p /mnt/test
root@host:~# mount /dev/sdf1 /mnt/test
mount: special device /dev/sdf1 does not exist
```

---

## 2nd try: [`umount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount) command

Now repeat the hole procedure with only changing the way I unmount my flash drive. Instead of clicking eject button, I type:

```
umount /dev/sdf1
```

Here is the result of [`df`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df):

```
root@host:~# df -h | grep sdf
root@host:~# df -ah | grep sdf
root@host:~#
```

[`df`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) result is probably as expected because it's the same as above... but here comes the [`blkid`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid):

```
root@host:~# blkid | grep sdf
/dev/sdf1: UUID="XXXX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX" LABEL="Debian 9.1.0 amd64 1" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="XXXXXXXX" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="XXXXXXXX-XX"
/dev/sdf2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="XXXX-XXXX" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="XXXXXXXX-XX"
```

Note that remounting works fine in opposite to the previous try:

```
root@host:~# df -h | grep sdf
root@host:~# mkdir -p /mnt/test
root@host:~# ls /mnt/test | wc -l
0
root@host:~# mount /dev/sdf1 /mnt/test
mount: /dev/sdf1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
root@host:~# ls /mnt/test | wc -l
24
```

---

## The question

Why is that?

What is the precise, underlying reason of above differences in [`blkid`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) output? Does [GNOME Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) do something more than [`umount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount) command? It seems to me that [GNOME File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) eject button is kind of 'permanent' unmount. Why?

Comment: It is a duplicate of that, that's an eject button, not an unmount button.

Comment: You're right. +1 I was looking for a similar thread but I haven't found [it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394957/why-is-usb-drive-not-visible-with-lsblk-after-having-been-ejected-from-thunar). Thanks!